# how to do document.ondrop in firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, google-chrome

The document.ondrop seems to work in chrome, but not in firefox?

Attached is an example:
http://auth.letschat.info/test2.php

If you drop a file on to the page it should pop up an alert box. However it doesn't work in firefox, but does in chrome.

When I use firefox console the document.ondrop handler is correctly set.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming the original javascript looks like this and works in Chrome:

```
document.ondrop=function(event){
    alert("hello");
}
```

It can be changed to work in both Firefox and Chrome. Firefox requires you to stop the default action from occuring when you drag a file over, which can be solved by using the ondragover event. The following javascript code will also work in Firefox:

```
document.ondragover = function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
}
document.ondrop=function(event){
    alert("hello");
}
```

I found this solution by looking at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_draganddrop.asp?output=print) and looking for the differences between their simple example and your code.

From [html5rocks](http://slides.html5rocks.com/#drag-in) on slide #18 there is also an html5 example of another way to use drag and drop by adding the listener to the page.